# Как работать с файлом по имени и ссылке в C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, файлы

Оборудование: C# под Visual Studio

Пусть имеется файл `text.txt`, у которого путь `C:\myfolder\text.txt`.

Необходимо указать имя этого файла для чтения таким образом:
`StreamReader("text.txt")`

Понятно, что просто так указать имя файла недостаточно. Но указывать абсолютный путь я не хочу.

Как указать ссылку на каталог `myfolder` или добавить в список ресурсов этот файл, чтобы Visual Studio понимала сама, где находится данный файл? Причем необходимо, чтобы файл не копировался в проект, а **оставался на своем месте.**

Я пытался:

1. добавить файл в рабочий каталог как связь (с помощью средств VS)
2. добавить ярлык в рабочий каталог на этот файл (с помощью проводника)
3. добавить файл в список ресурсов

Но VS все равно ищет файл в **рабочем каталоге**, ничего не находит и возникает ошибка `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "Could not find file...`.

Comment: `Но указывать абсолютный путь я не хочу.` как доставить письмо, если знаете имя, но не знаете адреса? Либо копируйте файл в рабочий каталог, либо каталог с файлом делайте рабочим.

Comment: `Environment.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\myfolder";`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, хорошая идея. Но немного не то, что я хотел.

Comment: @tym32167, ну если вы где-нибудь в сокровенном месте один раз напишите адрес какого-нибудь подъезда Москвы. То потом достаточно только имен и фамилий жильцов, чтобы понять кого вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: я потому и написал `либо каталог с файлом делайте рабочим`

Comment: Это именно то, что вам нужно. Среда разработки совершенно не при чём. Вы можете писать код в VS Code, Rider, MonoDevelop или просто в Блокноте. Запускать-то будете потом программу без них. Вот в самой программе и нужно указывать все пути. Кстати, рабочий каталог можно задать в ярлыке экзешника, при установке (в инсталляторе) - может это сгодится.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, то есть при запуске любого исполняемого файла, можно заранее указать какой рабочий каталог будет использовать этот исполняемый файл?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, благодарю вас, понял.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите через переменную глобальный единый путь для нужных вам файлов, и при смене пути файлов, вам только остается поменять а одном месте путь.

```
string mypth = "C:/myfolder";
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(mypth+"/text.txt");
```